# $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] not returning IP address

Tags: php, request

I'm trying to get the client IP address using the code `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`.

When I tried to `dd($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])`, it gives me the following output.

`string '::1' (length=3)`

What's the reason? Am I doing it wrong?

My target is to identify the user location based on the IP address and calling an external API.

Comment: Are you using localhost? If so, that means localhost

Comment: What IP address do I need to identify the location of the user?

Comment: If you are running the server on the same server as you are accessing the page you will get localhost. Go on a different network to see something different

Comment: So, there is no other way that I can get the real IP address of my connection atleast?

Comment: Put the website on a remote server and access it from your computer.

Comment: Alright. Will try that.

Comment: Meanwhile, what is the best way to get a JSON response for an API request something like this: `http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-city/?key=wehfihweuf&ip=70.27.250.191`using php?

Comment: You will have to open a new question for that with more detail. Sorry.

Comment: ok. For this, you can make an answer and I'll mark it as completed. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have a server on say your laptop, and you try to access it from the same laptop, the website sees it as it self and is represented in many different ways, and here are a few:

```
127.0.0.1
::1
localhost
```

To see the IP of your computer you can do the following:

1. Put your website on a remote server then access it, this will give you your Public IP address.
2. Put your website on another server on the same network and access it from a different computer on that network, and this will give the internal IP address for that computer.